# Finding the simplest equation for this curve shape

Tags: trigonometry, cubics

[image: curve in question]
This is the rough spline that I'm trying to find the simplest equation for.
The only data point constrains are {0,0} and {1024,256}

The closest I've got is this: [image]
How can I go about refining the equation so that it intersects the two points?
Or is there a better / simpler way of doing this other than with `tanh`?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function), if you are willing to relax the constraints a little.

Comment: See also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function#/media/File:Gjl-t(x).svg) for additional functions with the same shape.

Comment: Why did you include the [tag:cubic-equations] tag in your post?

Comment: Oh sorry, I mentioned cuberoot in an earlier version of the question. But thanks so much for that link! I found one that fits the 2 points.

Comment: You might want to post an answer to your question, so that this question doesn't remain unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

viable solution found:
[image: solution graph]
[image: solution table]
$\frac{x-512}{128+|x-512|}$*160+128

(thanks to [Joel Reyes Noche!](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/18398/joel-reyes-noche))

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with differential equations set up a convenient ordinary differential equation of an odd function with unity as slope ( or as desired) at $x=0,y=0 $ and slope tending asymptotically to zero as $ x \rightarrow \pm \infty.$